On a polynomial defined on the set of all reflections of a reflection group via the length function
Let $W$ be a finite reflection group and let $T_{W}:=T\subseteq W$ be the set of reflections in the reflection group in $W$. My goal is to compute the sum
$$P_{W}(x):=P(x)=\sum_{t\in T}x^{\ell(t)},$$
where $\ell:W\to\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ is the length function on $W$ (w.r.t. a fixed simple system).
In the case of the symmetric group $S_{n}$ it can be shown that the set of reflections in $S_{n}$ coincides with the set of transpositions of $S_{n}$ and so
$$ P(x)=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}x^{2j-2i-1} $$
which can be easily computed.
My question is: Can I compute the polynomial $P_{W}(x)$ for an arbitrary reflection group $W$? Is there a nice description of the reflections of an arbitrary reflection group?
